# How did Nagato gain his Rinnegan?

Tags: naruto

How was it exactly that Nagato came upon his Rinnegan?

Madara states that it was his, and that he gave it to him: how did he do that? Did he transplant it into Nagato, or did he transfer it otherwise?

Note: I do not recall whether this was explained in the manga or not.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well,

> Black Zetsu, which is the embodiment of Madara's willpower and thought (Yin), stated that he had indeed *transplanted* these eyes into him when he was a boy. When or how isn't stated, one can only speculate that Madara used White Zetsu or some other Zetsu for it.

Answer (score 9):

Like you said, it certainly was not mentioned.

> The best *guess* is that he used Zetsu to do it, since he was chained
>  to the Gedo Mazo.
>  
>  Apparently he knew he could use it in the distant future to revive
>  himself again.

Answer (score 9):

In Chapter 606,

> In Obito's flashback, Madara mentions that he did indeed transplant it into Nagato without him (Nagato) realising it. How exactly he did it is not explained, though it is likely he used a Gedo Mazo/Senju cells based technique similar to the one he used to "repair" Obito's body (without Obito realising it as well).